# show that $0.5 - \frac{ln(x)}x > 0$

Tags: logarithms

I try to show that 
$$
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{ln(x)} x > 0  
$$
on  $x \in (0, \infty)$ , 
any help would be appreciated, but the simplest way will be the best

Comment: Try looking at the derivative. It does not change sign.

Comment: Also, rearranging the inequality (with reversible steps) gives us $e^x >x^2$ which is clearly true.

Comment: just prove that the  second term  is always < 1/2

Answer (score 2):

We can rearrange 
$$0.5−\frac{\ln(x)}{x}>0$$
to be 
$$0.5>\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$
multiply the x over (which is always going to be positive)
$$\frac{1}{2}x>\ln(x)$$
make them each exponents of for $e^x$
$$e^{\frac{1}{2}x}>e^{\ln(x)}$$
which is 
$$e^{\frac{1}{2}x}>x$$
$$\sqrt{e}\cdot e^x>x$$
and exponential functions always grow faster than polynomial functions, and in this case, is always greater than x.

If you didn't like that solution, you could use calculus:
Take the derivative of $\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$

$$\frac{x\cdot\frac{1}{x}-\ln(x)\cdot1}{x^2}$$

and find where it equals goes from positive to negative: $1-\ln(x)=0$ @ $x = e$

so we know that because the slope goes positive to negative, we have a maximum @ $x = e$.

$$\ln(e)/e=\frac{1}{e}$$
which is our maximum of this function, which is less than 0.5, so we know that 
$$0.5>\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$
and thus 
$$0.5−\frac{\ln(x)}{x}>0$$

Comment: It's good to see 2 ways to solve the problem. However, exponential functions only grow faster than polynomials for large enough $x$.

Comment: Yes. Good clarification. (But in this case, it's pretty clear that $e^x$ is always bigger than x).

Comment: thanks a lot, the first way you've proposed is what I was looking for, but the second one is great too,

Comment: however that's e^x which grow faster that x^α, so I prefer the second one, thank

Comment: It would be great if you could check mark my answer, if you think it's good.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x>0$, the inequality is equivalent to
$$
x-2\ln x>0
$$
Find the minimum of the function
$$
f(x)=x-2\ln x
$$
using the fact that
$$
f'(x)=1-\frac{2}{x}
$$